# How to retrieve request payload from browser

Tags: browser, protractor, cucumber, jqxhr

I am using protractor-cucumber framework and want to retrieve the request payload from the browser's network tab through script. Can anyone help?

Comment: you can use `protractor-intercept` npm module to get information on all API calls made by browser. Have a look at https://github.com/bassettsj/protractor-intercept.

Comment: @SudharsanSelvaraj, can you provide more info on this module..